# VueJS Custom Component Import Works Sometimes

Tags: node.js, vue.js, import, vue-component

I have a VueJS component, `Image`, imported into two other different components, `A` and `B`.  `Image` works as expected on `A` but not on `B` (I initially get the `did you register the component?` error in the JS console).  Both `A` and `B`'s import statements are exactly the same.

When I go to `B` and change `Image`'s import statement to include `.vue` and save, the app auto-refreshes and everything on `B` works as expected.  As soon as I manually refresh the browser, `B`'s `Image` no longer works.

I'll then go back to `B`, remove the `.vue` from `Image`'s import statement and save, and lo and behold, the app auto-refreshes and everything on `B` works as expected.  Again, I manually refresh the browser, and `B`'s `Image` no longer works.

Meanwhile, `A` continues to work the whole time with no changes.

I'm declaring the component locally.  I've tried both:

```
components: {
  Image
}
```

and

```
components: {
  "image": Image
}
```

Both give me the same behavior on `B`.  Namely, simply modifying the file so that everything is 'correct' and then saving, results in the app auto-refreshing and `B` working as expected.

But as soon as I try to run the app straight out of source control, without modifying anything, `B` stops working.  Only after changing something and then saving it, does it work.

I'm at a loss.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you share a simplified version in codesanbox

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, unfortunately, I can't.  I've since found other SO questions with the same issue.  It seems to have to do with circular references, but I don't think I have any.

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid the reserved keyword as a component name. `image` is a reserved [keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image). Whenever you use `<image>|<Image>` into Vue it renders as `image` which is reserved.